# Why is ground beef red on the bottom also?

Tags: food-safety

Recently, I have been buying ground beef in one pound packages that is red throughout. Last evening I bought a 6 pound bulk package (because of the significant savings) from the same store. The meat was red on all surfaces including underneath, but grayish brown throughout the middle. Is the Styrofoam piece on the bottom of the packaging air permeable also?

Comment: related, but doesn't answer this specific question : http://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/10504/67

Answer (score 1):

Because oxygen is still carried through the packaging, but it doesn't travel very far in the meat. This is normal.