# 3 day old steak turning brown from the inside out

Tags: food-safety, meat, steak, spoilage

I have a 10oz. steak I cut 3 days ago. It was stored on peach paper, which is oxygenated. It is beginning to brown from the inside out. The exterior is fine, no slime, no odour. But when cooked, it looked medium well at 120*F. It also tasted dry. I get that age would make it dry. I`m just wondering why it is browning on the inside. Any ideas what would cause this?

Comment: Hey there! I think you answered it yourself - it's the oxidation. Again that is also the cause of it cooking and drying out faster. Next time brine in moisturizing substance to avoid.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Beef: Red on the outside, brown on the inside](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/10504/beef-red-on-the-outside-brown-on-the-inside)

Answer (score -1):

I've heard that some stores will actually use some type of food safe bleach to extend the life of their meat products. It is possible that the meat you purchased was treated in this manner which would not have an affect on the inside of the steak. This would make the inside age quicker than the outside.  Just a thought.

Comment: Possible to provide a link or reference to the use of bleach?